# Find out / customize Symfony Forms Twig block name

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I want to override how parts of my form is rendered, but I always forget to which twig block names symfony forms renders. If the block is not found, I get no feedback why not was not found, and how it should have been called.

Example:

```php
class SetPasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class);
        $builder->add('repeatPlainPassword', PasswordType::class);
    }
}
```

Three essential questions:

- How does symfony forms determine the twig block name(s) for the `SetPasswordType`?
- How can I look this up?
- How can I customize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific type, the twig `widget` block name is `set_password_widget`.

Override it in your form theme like this:

```
{% block set_password_widget %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ form_row(form.plainPassword) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{ form_row(form.repeatPlainPassword) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

### How to override a block

- Determine the block prefix, which by default depends on the class name. For `SetPasswordType`, it is `set_password`
- Decide which block you want to render. If you want to change the layout, likely you will override the `row` block. If you want to change the input, likely you will override the `widget` block. Refer to the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-fragment-naming
- Join the block prefix and the block name together. For the `widget` block of the `SetPasswordType`, you want to override `set_password_widget`.
- Place the twig block in your form theme.

### Troubleshoot if overriding fails

- Check that the twig block is in a file configured in `twig.form_themes` or otherwise as a form theme included.
- Inspect `$blockPrefixes` in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BaseType::buildView` to see which block prefixes were determined. The last entry in the array will be looked for first.
- Inspect `$blockNameHierarchy` in `Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock` to see which specific blocks are looked for. The last entry in the array will be looked for first.

### Detailed walkthrough

The names of the blocks are build up in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BaseType::buildView`, within the `$blockPrefixes` variable. `$blockPrefixes` defines the following priority (first mentioned = highest priority. It is stored in reverse!):

- the unique block name (built up hierarchically based on property names).
- the block prefix, if one is configured
- the name of the type (if inheriting from `AbstractType`, the name is generated in `AbstractType::getBlockPrefix()`)
- the name of all parent types (following the chain of the `FormTypeInterface::getParent()` method).

For example, it could look like this:

```php
$blockPrefixes = [
  0 => "form", # because `AbstractType::getParent()` returns `FormType`
  1 => "set_password", # our type, name resolved automatically depending on class name 

  ## at this position, a block prefix would be included if one is configured 

  2 => "_set_password" # the hierarchical unique name, prefixed with `_`. for the plainPassword field, this value would be "searchAndRenderBlock". 
];
```

When the form is rendered by twig, the `Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock` is called with a respective `$blockNameSuffix` (for example `widget` or `row`). The `$blockNameHierarchy` is created by suffixing each potential prefix with the `$blockNameSuffix`.

For `$blockNameSuffix == "row"` it would then look like this:

```php
$blockNameHierarchy = [
  0 => "form_widget",
  1 => "set_password_widget",
  2 => "_set_password_widget"];
```

These blocks are looked for, and the one with the highest priority which can be found is chosen. The later in the array, the higher the priority.

### Customize block prefixes

You can customize the prefixes like this:

```php
class SetPasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, ['mapped' => false]);
        $builder->add('repeatPlainPassword', PasswordType::class, ['mapped' => false]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefault('block_prefix', 'my_custom_prefix');
        $resolver->setDefault('block_name', 'my_custom_name');
    }
}
```

This will result in

```php
$blockPrefixes = [
  0 => "form", 
  1 => "set_password", # this will stay the same as its resolved depending on type name

  2 => "my_custom_prefix", # as per our configuration, we now have a custom prefix

  3 => "_my_custom_name" # the custom name will be used to determine the hierarchical name
];
```